# MPLABX XC8 Compiler - implicit signed to unsigned conversion?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, xc8, mplab-x

Why am I getting :

> (373)implicit signed to unsigned conversion

by doing:

`fan_on_hh = hh + fan_hh_increment`

All `fan_on_hh`, `hh` and `fan_hh_increment` are `unsigned char`.

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435139/impliciting-signed-to-unsigned-conversion-mplab-xc8) suggests to do this:

`fan_on_hh = (unsigned char) hh + fan_hh_increment`

But I keep getting the same warning by doing that.

Is there a way to stop these warnings?

Comment: You get implicit conversion to `int` in the addition.

Comment: Doing `+` promotes the inputs, and the result, back up to `int`.  You have to cast the result of the `+` (note `+` has lower precedence than a cast).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules for more.

Comment: Use `fan_on_hh = (unsigned char)(hh + fan_hh_increment)` or maybe `fan_on_hh = (hh + fan_hh_increment)&UCHAR_MAX`.  IMO, this warning should not occur as conversion `int` to `unsigned char` is well defined.  -  IOWs, a weak analysis tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer types smaller than `int` (e.g. `unsigned char`) are promoted to `int` when an operation is performed on them. If all values of the original type can be represented as an `int`, the value of the smaller type is converted to an `int`.
So in your example
`hh` and `fan_hh_increment` are promoted to `int` before the addition.
When you want to stop the warning, you had to cast the result to `unsigned char`:

```
fan_on_hh = (unsigned char) (hh + fan_hh_increment);
```

Comment: it really worked.. I have made a mistake at reading that artikle... thanks for the correction..

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you can cast the result of the addition, which is probably the right way to go about it. But if that message is particularly annoying, the manual suggests (section 4.5.3.1 Disabling Messages) adding some flags to the command line to disable it:

```
-Xparser -Wno-sign-conversion
```